# Spell check in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, spell-checking

I use SVN tortoise (English version). It is possible to attach dictionary in other language?
I would like to have checked spell when I write description for commits (in polish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-intro-install-spell.html):

> TortoiseSVN includes a spell checker which allows you to check your
>   commit log messages. This is especially useful if the project language
>   is not your native language. The spell checker uses the same
>   dictionary files as OpenOffice and Mozilla.
>
> The installer automatically adds the US and UK English dictionaries.
>   **If you want other languages, the easiest option is simply to install
>   one of TortoiseSVN's language packs. This will install the appropriate
>   dictionary files as well as the TortoiseSVN local user interface.**
>   After the installation finishes, the dictionary will be available too.

Comment: Firefox dictionaries work fine but you may need to *rename* the files: TortoiseSVN expects e.g. "es_ES.aff"; the original "es-ES.aff" will not work.