# Disable german spellchecker in TortoiseSVN on Windows 10

Tags: svn, localization, windows-10, tortoisesvn, spell-checking

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows 10 and want to use the English (default) spell-checker in TortoiseSVN. Instead, it uses a German language checker that I neither installed nor want. It is exactly the opposite from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223552/spell-check-in-tortoise-svn).

[image]

Note, that I have changed my Windows locale to EN-US, because [the TortoiseSVN manual](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-intro-install-spell.html) says that the following strategy applies to TortoiseSVN:

> 2. If no project language is set, or that language is not installed, try the language corresponding to the Windows locale.

here are my Windows language settings. I even specified that my Location to be in the US (which I'm not), but still it does not work.

[image: Windows language settings]

Any ideas?

Comment: This Problem drives me crazy. Have this on every working machine and see it for all my coworkers. Also the way how tortoiseSVN handles languages is very fiddly

Answer (score 5):

Quoting an [answer](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3156445) from a thread at the TortoiseSVN discussion forums:

> On Win8 and later, TSVN uses the spell checker that's built into the OS 
>   itself. And the language it uses is the one of the OS, or if you set the 
>   `tsvn:projectlanguage` then it uses that language.
>
> So you have to set the `tsvn:projectlanguage` to English [for every project] to get the correct spell checking.

An alternative would be to install the language pack (in your case English) to the OS and use English as default system language.

Comment: is there a way to mix two or more languages?

Comment: I'm not aware of such an option.

Comment: For me changing the "Region format" option to an English format works. This is the setting used to determine things like times and dates.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have tsvn:projectlanguage set for the project

Open TortoiseSVN ==> Settings ==> General ==> Dialogs 2
and check "Only use spellchecker when tsvn:projectlanguage is set"

This will disable spell checking, at least you don't have every word underlined with red and can read what you type clearly

Tortoise SVN developers should have add an option to disable their not working spell-checker completely, but they seem to not care at all

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround with a custom dictionary.
Go to the TortoiseSVN installation folder

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Languages\
```

and open the file `en_GB.dic` in a text editor.

Copy the whole content into the custom dictionary file located under

```
%APPDATA%\TortoiseSVN\1031.dic
```

Finally, replace the word suffixes with RegEx.
Search for `^(.*)/.*$`
and replace with
`$1`.